# SQlite MAX query returns empty sometime

Tags: android, mysql, ios, sql, sqlite

I am trying to get max value in a column. Many times i able to get the max value. But few times nothing returned

Below is the the two sample executes with logs where i am getting nothing and value

**Getting none**

-log- query=select MAX(id) from product WHERE price = ?

-log- args count=1

-log- args[0]=31

```
cursor=db.rawQuery(query, args);
```

-log- cursor.getCount()=1

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst())
```

-log- Move the cursor to the first row succeeded

-log- cursor.getString(0)=

-log- cursor.getType(0)=3

-log- cursor.getColumnName(0)=MAX(id)

**Getting value**

-log-query=select MAX(id) from product WHERE price = ?

-log- args count=1

-log- args[0]=31

```
Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(query, args);
```

-log- cursor.getCount()=1

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst())
```

-log- Move the cursor to the first row succeeded

-log- cursor.getString(0)=3

-log- cursor.getType(0)=1

-log- cursor.getColumnName(0)=MAX(id)

Comment: What is the data type for `price`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff data type of price is String

Comment: Does every row have a value for price and for id?

Comment: @Karakuri Yes, each row have a value for price and id

Comment: @Karakuri yor are right. Value missing in the id field, after web sync empty value stored in the id field. Thanks.

Comment: The aggregate max() function in SQLite will return NULL if there are  no non-NULL values in the group. If after the WHERE clause is applied the `id` column of all rows contains NULL, then this might be the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add single quote with pricevalue because price  is type of string,So use your query as

```
select MAX(id) from product WHERE price = "'" + pricevalue + "'";
```

But recommended solution is to use `query` instead of `rawQuery`like

```
cursor = db.query("product", new String [] {"MAX(id)"}, "price=?",
            new String[] { pricevalue }, null, null, null);
```

Note: **pricevalue**  will be value of price.

Comment: I have tried the first one, i am getting null value for cursor.getString(0) and for cursor.getType(0)is 0 and curso count is 1.

Comment: @user3551469 try recommended solution and null value what ? post logcat exception.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is one of floating point conversion.  Try expressing the `where` clause as:

```
where abs((price + 0) - pricevalue) < 0.005
```

You may also have problems with prices that are, say, `'$5.00'`, but the `pricevalue` is `'5'`.  Merely quoting the string won't help.